# Having Trouble adding parse to eclipse library

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm currently developing an Android app. I'm using parse for database. I added parse to the "libs" folder but keep getting the error: "The import parse cannot be resolved". I added the parse .jar file to build path and it seemed to fix that error, however, I'm getting error in run time: "cannot create parseObj subclass".

I would be appreciate it if anybody can help me with this problem

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays putting the JAR in the libs folder should be enough but if for some reasons it does not work for you I suggest you to add the  JAR on your classpath when compiling and running.

- Right click project
- select property
- select add external jar
- clean, build and run

here is a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

hello go through below link :-

https://github.com/vishaljain790/ParseLibrary.git

Here you will get an example with proper code formation....